# GuavaCache expireAfterWrite() is causing too many blocked threads

Tags: java, multithreading, guava, contention

We have a use case where our data is becoming stale after some time. Hence we chose expireAfterWrite cache eviction strategy. However this is causing too many blocked threads in threadpool. Any idea why this might be happening and if there is any way to avoid this.

sample thread pool log:

```
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.112-b15
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 7546: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack$SNode, boolean, long) @bci=160, line=460 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.lang.Object, boolean, long) @bci=102, line=362 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=11, line=941 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=134, line=1066 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

Thread 1268: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=175 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt() @bci=1, line=836 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=72, line=997 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(int) @bci=24, line=1304 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get() @bci=2 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get() @bci=4 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(java.util.concurrent.Future) @bci=3 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.waitForValue() @bci=4 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.waitForLoadingValue(com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache$ReferenceEntry, java.lang.Object, com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache$ValueReference) @bci=44 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(java.lang.Object, int, com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.CacheLoader) @bci=122 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(java.lang.Object, com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.CacheLoader) @bci=17 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(java.lang.Object) @bci=6 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.coral.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(java.lang.Object) @bci=5 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.csapp.services.SmartVideoCacheService.getVideos(com.amazon.csapp.utils.MetricsContext, com.amazon.csapp.utils.AmazonRequestInfo) @bci=33, line=214 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.csapp.rest.resource.v2.VideoResource.getVideos(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) @bci=67, line=56 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=88 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=6, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=56, line=498 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=3, line=81 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=39, line=128 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(java.lang.Object, javax.ws.rs.core.Request) @bci=6, line=195 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(java.lang.Object, org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest) @bci=3, line=94 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest, java.lang.Object) @bci=13, line=353 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest) @bci=103, line=343 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(java.lang.Object) @bci=5, line=102 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run() @bci=198, line=237 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call() @bci=4, line=271 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call() @bci=1, line=267 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(java.util.concurrent.Callable, boolean) @bci=36, line=315 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Producer, boolean) @bci=2, line=297 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=9, line=267 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=25, line=322 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest) @bci=22, line=211 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest) @bci=5, line=979 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(java.net.URI, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=115, line=344 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(java.net.URI, java.net.URI, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=9, line=372 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=321, line=335 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.csapp.servlet.JerseyServletContainer.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=15, line=26 (Compiled frame)
 - org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=39, line=218 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=376, line=290 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=101, line=206 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=804, line=233 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=365, line=191 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=327, line=470 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=64, line=127 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=6, line=103 (Compiled frame)
 - com.amazon.tomcat.valves.QueryLogValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=47, line=78 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=24, line=617 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=42, line=109 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(org.apache.coyote.Request, org.apache.coyote.Response) @bci=158, line=293 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(java.net.Socket) @bci=545, line=859 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(java.net.Socket) @bci=73, line=610 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() @bci=41, line=503 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)
```

Comment: (1) You can add `refreshAfterWrite` to hide the load times, (2) there may be a [bug](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2774) causing the threads to be stuck

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a [dedicated thread](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#when-does-cleanup-happen) to [refresh](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#refresh) the cache's values more frequently. As Ben Manes suggests configuring a `refreshAfterWrite` that's lower than your expiration threshold would also help, but you'll want to override `reload()` to do the work asynchronously.

It's also possible there are hotspots in your code causing numerous separate paths to try to hit the same cache keys simultaneously. If you don't expect that behavior (e.g. you expected approximately one thread at a time to be accessing a key) you might want to investigate whether there's some missing locking semantics causing too many threads to be reading from the cache at the same time, or a different cause of hotspots such as unusual request patterns.